# Proving that $ (a \cup b)^* = (b^*(a\cup\lambda)b^*)^*$?

Tags: regular-expressions, proof-techniques

How would I prove that these two regexes are equal to one another? $$ (a \cup b)^* = (b^*(a\cup\lambda)b^*)^*$$

I'm permitted to use the following regular expression identities.

[image]

Comment: Please do not delete your questions after receiving answers. That's against our policies.

Answer (score 3):

One of the equalities 12 tell us that now
$(u\cup v)^* = u^*(vu^*)^*$.
Applying this to the last expression we obtain
$(b\cup (a\cup\lambda))^*$.

Also $(u\cup \lambda)^* = (u^*\lambda^*)^* = 
(u^* \lambda)^* = (u^*)^* = u^*$.

Do you have associativity of $\cup$ so that $(b\cup (a\cup\lambda))^* = ((b\cup a)\cup\lambda))^*$? It should be a basic property.

Comment: No I don't have associativity. Which is why I can't seem to prove this directly from the table itself.

Comment: Also, re-reading your answer I don't see how your second line for $ u^* $ is used? But, I can derive what we would get from associativy by starting with $ (b \cup a)^* $ and using the second line in reverse.

Comment: That part in reverse is what I meant. I do not know how to solve the remainder without using associativity. sorry.